# Is より used in superlative function here?

Tags: grammar, particle-より

The following is an excerpt from a conversation between me and my language partner:
クジラ肉は規制があるので、食べる機会は少ないのですが、私が住んでいる地域では、馬肉より手に入りやすいです

My attempt at translation:
"Concerning whalemeat, because there are regulations, chances to eat (it) are few and concerning the prefecture I live in, horse meat is the easiest to go into your hand."
I've never before encountered より in the function of marking the superlative, only comparison (...のほう...より...) and in the function of "from". So I wanted to ask whether I got it right here ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> クジラ肉は規制があるので、食べる機会は少ないのですが、私が住んでいる地域では、馬肉**より**手に入りやすいです。

I find that より normally translates well as 'rather than' or 'compared to'. In this case the latter translation works best:

> 馬肉**より**手に入りやすいです
>   compared to horse meat it's easy to get.

So it's not a superlative but a comparison just like you expected.

> Because whale meat is regulated there aren't many chances to eat it, but in the area where I live it's easier to get than horse meat.

Answer (score 0):

手に入る would be closest to 'acquire' or 'get' in English.

（クジラ肉は）馬肉より手に入りやすい。

My translation would be 'There are regulations on whale meat, so there are fewer chances to eat it. However, where I live, it is easier to get than horse meat.'.

Comment: I see we disagree one which one is easier to get. If I'm wrong could you please explain why? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. I mistakenly formed a conclusion that I thought was logical given the context. I have edited. I read it as 馬肉はより手に入りやすい, which would have been different.

Answer (score 0):

日本語{にほんご}で失礼{しつれい}します。

文のうち、

> （クジラ肉は）規制があるので、食べる機会は少ないの**ですが**
>   **But** there are not many chances to eat whale meat because it is regulated (by Washington Convention?)

これは補足的{ほそくてき}な文{ぶん}です。敬語{けいご}（です）と一緒{いっしょ}に消します。

> クジラ肉は、私が住んでいる地域では、馬肉より手に入りやすい

位置{いち}を交換{こうかん}します。

> 私が住んでいる地域では、クジラ肉は、馬肉より**手に入りやすい**
>   Whale meat is easier to obtain than horse meat in the area where I live, .

手に入りやすい＝手に入（る）＋（し）易{やす}い

手に入る means "obtain".

し易{やす}い、やりやすい means "do easily".

> クジラ肉**は**、馬肉**より**

"より"は、比較{ひかく}、対比{たいひ}（comparison, more than）です。

"the easiest"ではなく、"easier than"になります。

Finally,

> 私が住んでいる地域では、クジラ肉は、馬肉より手に入りやすいです
>  
>   Whale meat is easier to obtain than horse meat in the area where I live.
>   ですが、クジラ肉は規制されているので、食べる機会は少ないです
>   But there are not many chances to eat because it is regulated.

Comment: "few chance(es)" would be better "Not many chances or a few chances" as in the other answer?　クジラ肉自体は滅多に食べる機会はないが馬肉に比べたら少しはあるという感じで。